# Next Previous Post in wordpress with previous / next link with title?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, child-theme

I recently tried the previous post and the next post button link. I do that with image in the left and right side of the site.Its working perfect.But i didn't know how to do this

**For Example:**

```
 <div class="alignleftfp">
                        <?php next_post('%', '<img class="imgalign" src="' . WP_CONTENT_URL . '/uploads/1.png" alt="Next" /> ', 'no');
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="alignrightfp">

                        <?php previous_post('%', '<img class="imgalign" src="' . WP_CONTENT_URL . '/uploads/1.png" alt="Next" />  ', 'no');
                        ?>
                    </div>
```

Is it Possible to Show the Previous Post and Next Post Link with Under Title in every Bottom of the Post. Here is the Screenshot.
[image]

**EDITED:**

See what I edited the code.

```
<?php 

function nextprev() {

?>
  <div class="alignleftfp">
                        <?php next_post_link('%link', '<img class="imgalign" src="' . WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/testplugin/assets/type1/5.png" alt="Next" /> %title'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="alignrightfp">
                        <?php previous_post_link('%link', '%title <img class="imgalign" src="' . WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/testplugin/assets/type1/6.png" alt="Next" />'); ?>
                    </div>

<?php
$content = get_the_content(); 
 echo $content;
}

add_action('the_content','nextprev');
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like so, I guess:

```
<div class="alignleftfp">
    <?php next_post_link('%link', '<img class="imgalign" src="' . WP_CONTENT_URL . '/uploads/1.png" alt="Next" /> %title'); ?>
</div>
<div class="alignrightfp">
    <?php previous_post_link('%link', '%title <img class="imgalign" src="' . WP_CONTENT_URL . '/uploads/1.png" alt="Next" />'); ?>
</div>
```

PS. You shouldn't use `next_post`/`previous_post` functions - they're deprecated.

**EDIT**

Just read [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter docs. It SHOULD NOT echo anything. It should return it's value. So your function should look like this:

```
function nextprev($content) {
    ob_start(); ?>
    <div class="alignleftfp">
        <?php next_post_link('%link', '<img class="imgalign" src="' . WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/testplugin/assets/type1/5.png" alt="Next" /> %title'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="alignrightfp">
        <?php previous_post_link('%link', '%title <img class="imgalign" src="' . WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/testplugin/assets/type1/6.png" alt="Next" />'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php $my_next_prev = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean();

    return $content . $my_next_prev;
}

add_action('the_content','nextprev');
```

Comment: Thanks When i Use the condition with add_action hook to the_content the existing content disappear. So I use get_the_content(); still i have an problem that link comes top of the post. I use echo to get the content also i tried the return option to get the content still blank post with corresponding post happen

Comment: You shouldn't use it inside `the_content` hook, but in template file. If you really have to do it with `the_template` hook, just make sure you return it and not output it... `the_content` filter should NOT output anything. It should return the value.

Comment: Thanks For Awesome Response. I edited the code. I am Not sure I tried to create the custom plugin. I tried the_content hook with echo of get_the_content(); , also i tried the return option still nothing happen. Any Idea

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks it works but it should look like previous post and the nextpost link is appear top of the content ? why

Comment: How can i show the next and previous below the post?

Comment: You want these links before or after post content?

Comment: After Post Content

Comment: OK, updated answer.